# Python CSV reader return Row as list

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, parsing, csv

Im trying to parse a CSV using python and would like to be able to index items in a row so they can be accessed using `row[0]`, `row[1]` and so on.

So far this is my code:

```
def get_bitstats():
    url = 'http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD'
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(data)
    obj = BitData()
    for row in dictReader:

        obj.datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row['0'])/1000000)
        q = db.Query(BitData).filter('datetime', obj.datetime)
        if q != None:
            raise ValueError(obj.datetime + 'is already in database')
        else:
            obj.price = row['1']
            obj.amount = row['2']
            obj.put()
```

This returns `KeyError: '0'` and I have no idea how to set it up. I did input this into an interactive shell and when running

```
for row in dictReader:
    print row
```

I get this as the output:

```
{'1': '3'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '2'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '9'}
{'1': '8'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '4'}
{'1': '4'}
{'1': '', None: ['']}
{'1': '4'}
{'1': '2'}
{'1': '.'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '5'}
{'1': '7'}
{'1': '1'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '', None: ['']}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '.'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '1'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '5'}
{'1': '4'}
{'1': '2'}
{'1': '5'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '0'}
{'1': '1'}
{'1': '3'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '2'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '9'}
{'1': '8'}
{'1': '6'}
{'1': '4'}
{'1': '4'}
```

and on and on for thousands and thousands of lines. ( as Im sure the CSV is thousands of digits)

Why is my CSV printing this way and is there anyway to separate a row into a list of 3 `ints` such as [130534543, 47.00009, 23001.9000]

EDIT:

as the Answer states I was using the wrong csv function in my code above but even though fixing it gave me a list the list itself was in the same format as the dict such that:

```
['1']
['2']
['1']
['3']
['8']
['3']
['5']
.
.
.
```

It turns out I also had to remove the `.read()` from `data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()`.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should take great care doing put()s inside iterative loops. Instead consider batching the puts. Huge performance gains in most cases. Also ask yourself if you want to  commit to a put with indices, and the resultant reliance on the query inside your loop. Could you denormalize into a keyed record? This will have a huge affect on performance replacing your query with a get, and no indices on the put.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. If as you said batching the `put()`s will help performance then I'll do just that. As for using a keyed record I don't really know much about that and will be looking into it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`csv.reader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) will return each row as a list

```
reader = csv.reader(data)

for line_list in reader:
   pass
   # line_list is a list of the data contained in a row so you can access line_list[0]
```

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. I kept looking through my code and the CSV/Python documentation and never noticed I was using DictReader(). Thank you